# DNN CMS training

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

Whats the best way to start to train an end user in a CMS like DOTNETNUKE?
The end user will want to add edit and delete there own content. They will need to install modules and understand how everything works?

Should i create a manual? is there a way to plan some training?

any ideas?

edit: the end users are VERY I.T illiterate, they struggled to even understand the rich text editor. I need to train them on how to use the form and list module and the HTML module for editting content. They want a document of some sort, this is really old school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PD24, for what most customers do it usually only takes 5-10 minutes of training.  I usually create a couple [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/) Videos which is a free screen and audio recording tool. I go through and do voice over as I create a page, edit text, add photos, add  modules and record it. Then I send them the links they can reference if they ever need a reminder.

Works great! (boooo to manuals, no one reads those and they take a lot of time to make!)
& [DNNcreative](http://www.dnncreative.com/) is probably too detailed for your client, that's a good resource for DNN implementers.

Answer (score 2):

We have a variety of videos in the video library on [DotNetNuke.com](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library.aspx) you could point users to those for specific topics.

We (DotNetNuke Corp) also provide custom training solutions, we could develop a custom training program for your client that fits the scope of your project and delivery requirements. If you want more info feel free to email me at `training@dnncorp.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into www.dnncreative.com, they have some awesome tutorials for developers and users.